# Avoid having to double-click to toggle Bootstrap dropdown

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using a Bootstrap dropdown menu. The problem is that it never drops down upon the first click; I need to click 2 times for it to be toggled. I guess the click event is somehow getting stuck somewhere before propagating down...

Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: provide a demo code to understand the problem. You can use [http://jsfiddle.net/](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

If someone is using angular with `ui-bootstrap` module along with normal bootstrap HTML dropdown definition, there are also two clicks needed.

```
<li class="dropdown">
   <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
   [...]
</li>
```

=> Removing the `data-toggle="dropdown"` will fix the issue.

Opening the dropdown with one click will work after this.

Reference:
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2294

Comment: WOW!!! I have exactly the same issue! I'm using ui-bootstrap and angular. Works well know.. thanks for sharing!!

Comment: This was fixed in UI-Bootstrap 0.12. To anybody who had this problem  after having upgraded to 0.12, simply add back `data-toggle="dropdown"` as you've removed previously.

Comment: What about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24218663/avoid-having-to-double-click-to-toggle-bootstrap-dropdown#answer-50253521), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24218663/avoid-having-to-double-click-to-toggle-bootstrap-dropdown#answer-52554398), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24218663/avoid-having-to-double-click-to-toggle-bootstrap-dropdown#answer-52569748) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24218663/avoid-having-to-double-click-to-toggle-bootstrap-dropdown#answer-52848502)? There are issues by using only the bootstrap.bundle.min.js?

Comment: 2020 and angular 9.1.7: this anwer still saved me. In angular 9.0.7 the issue didn't exist.

Comment: 2021 only the removing of the `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` solved the issue, drawback still unknown

Answer (score 90):

In Bootstrap 4, `bootstrap.min.js` and `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` now conflict in dropdown.

By removing `bootstrap.min.js`, the dropdown double click issue will resolved.

Comment: It seems to solve the problem, but what are the implications e.g. of using only the bootstrap.bundle.min.js?

Comment: Yes. use anyone of those. I suggest to use bootstrap.bundle.min.js . Because we don't need to add popper.js and other dependencies.

Comment: OMG! You are the Man! :D

Comment: cool , i also faced the same issue . thanks for the answer man

Comment: Idk if this is a good, solution,but... it works... so... I'm just going to pretend its the best... You're a genius, +1 vote.

Comment: in my case bootstrap.min.js was refered twice.I removed one.

Answer (score 37):

This may happen if somehow Bootstrap is included twice in your project.

If bootstrap.min.js and  bootstrap.bundle.min.js(bootstrap and popper js) both included in project, it means redundant bootstrap js.

The js combination should be like this:
Either : bootstrap.bundle.min.js only
Or : bootstrap.min.js AND popper.min.js
For detailed information, visit https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/contents/

Comment: It seems to solve the problem, but what are the implications e.g. of using only the bootstrap.bundle.min.js?

Comment: bootstrap.bundle.min.js comes with some extra features along with bootstrap js like popperjs. If your application is using popperjs and bootstrap, you can include the bootstrap.bundle.min.js. If not, you don't want to include bundle js with the larger size.

Comment: Super answer. Was using a datatables bundle AND separate bs4 include so removing it from the bundle fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

In BootStrap 4, One should not include both "bootstrap.bundle.min.js" and "bootstrap.min.js". This will cause the DropDown issue. Only Keep "bootstrap.bundle.min.js" as it will have all required code.

Comment: thx fixed the problem, I thought that somewhere a double event

Comment: And that's the real winner. Solves this issue complete. Also keep in mind to load jquery  before bootstrap. In my case jQuery 3.4.1 and Bootstrap 4.3.1.

Answer (score 10):

This happens because the Twitter Bootstrap syntax for their drop downs include a `href` tag. You will need to `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation` to prevent this from happening. Something like this will do the trick:

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Perfect! However I am somehow surprised they don't already include this in their bootstrap js file.

Comment: I'm guessing that when using just Bootstrap, using href is the expected behaviour. However when using Angular, you don't want to use that. It sucks, though.

Answer (score 6):

Like @rajaneesh-singh told us above, this bug occurs when  Bootstrap is included twice.

In my case, I had a duplicate with the offical bootstrap and with the twitter version:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

I just removed the twitter version and everything is working well now.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue as jaybro in https://stackoverflow.com/a/27278529/1673289, however their solution didn't help.

The way to fix for both cases was to add:

```
data-disabled="true"
```

onto the element which has the `data-toggle="dropdown"` attribute.

Answer (score 4):

I solved the issue by removing link to bootstrap.bundle.js and adding a link to popper.js

**Before**

```
<script src="bootstrap/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

**After**

```
<script src="bootstrap/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Note that I downloaded the bootstrap files and stored them in a directory called 'bootstrap'. Inside it I had three different directories 'css', 'js', 'jquery'.

Answer (score 4):

if use bootstrap4, remove bootstrap.bundle.min.js.
I had the same problem and it was fixed

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the other answers don't work.

In `application.js`, I had:

```
//= require popper.min
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

Removing bootstrap-sprockets fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I came across the same issue recently, i solved it by writing custom script:

```
   <div class="filter-dropdown text-right">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Edit</button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
         <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
         <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
         <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>



    $(".filter-dropdown").on("click", ".dropdown-toggle", function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().addClass("show");
        $(this).attr("aria-expanded", "true");
        $(this).next().addClass("show"); 
      });
```

Comment: It fixed the issue as I tried also the other solutions with no help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This may also happen if you have more than one bootstrap.js files! Check if you still have an older version and remove that script.

Answer (score 1):

By looking within the source code of angular.ui.bootstrap and the native bootstrap.js they have both handlers for dropdowns.

Proposed Solution:
adjust angular.ui.bootstrap **dropdownToggle** directive restrict only to "A" attributes.
so by resolving this issue you need to modify dropdownToggle restrict "CA" into "A" this will hide Class looker from angular.ui.bootstrap which has been already handled by bootstrap.js

for the minified version of angular.ui.bootstrap look for this line
directive("dropdownToggle",function(){return{restrict:**"CA"**,require:"?^dropdown",link:function(a,b,c,d){

replace "CA" with "A".

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I found that on some pages I would have to double click and other pages were single click.

Removing `data-toggle="dropdown"` made the double clicks into single and broke the singles.

I compared the html in the dev tool (because the same html is being served) and found on my double click pages the div with data-toggle looked like this:

```
<div id="notifications" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle"
     aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
```

But the single click html looks like this:

```
<div id="notifications" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">
```

So, in the document ready, I used attr detection and the prevent default answer and it made my double click opens into single click opens:

```
if (!($('#notifications').attr('aria-haspopup') == undefined &&
    $('#notifications').attr('aria-expanded') == undefined))
{
    $('.dropdown-toggle').click(function (e) { return false; });
}
```